# Вывод массива из async task c#

Tags: c#, firebase

Есть такой код:

```
public async Task<float[]> Get_Data()
{
    FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetTaskAsync("MyData");
    Data todo = response.ResultAs<Data>();

    float[] data = new float[3];

    data[0] = todo.PlayerPos_X;
    data[1] = todo.PlayerPos_Y;
    data[2] = todo.PlayerPos_Z;

    return data;
}
```

Он подключается к firebase и тащит из него 3 переменные, после чего они записываются в массив.

Пытаюсь вызвать этот метод:

```
tesT_firebase = new tesT_firebase();
tesT_firebase.init_firebase();
MessageBox.Show(tesT_firebase.Get_Data()[0]);
```

Выпадает с ошибкой:

> Ошибка    CS0021  Не удается применить индексирование через [] к выражению
>   типа "Task"

Как мне получить этот массив?

Answer (score 5):

> Как мне получить этот массив?

С помощью `await`:

```
MessageBox.Show((await tesT_firebase.Get_Data())[0]);
```